# To Calculate the Robo facing direction and its Position after moving in the given direction using java

Tags: java, collections

I have a 5*5 matrix and initally the robo is at co ordinates (2,2) facing "north". Robo moves in the direction Left,Right,Up,Down,Left. I have to Calculate the co ordinates of the robo after the movement(LRUDL) and its final facing direction.

Below is the code i have tried, but i am not able to add the logic for finding the robo final direction after the movement. It would be great if someone could help me on this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FinalPosition {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        System.out.println("Enter the moving direction:");
        String move = br1.readLine();
        //String move = "LRUDL"; 
        position(move); 

    }

    private static void position(String move) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        System.out.println("Enter the X axis co ordinates:");
        int xaxis = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the Y axis co ordinates:");
        int yaxis = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the initial direction of the robot");
        String direction = br.readLine(); 

        int l = move.length();
        int countUp = 0, countDown = 0; 
        int countLeft = 0, countRight = 0; 
        int x =0;
        int y= 0;
        int count= 0;

        char [] c=move.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(c);

        for(int i=0; i< c.length; i++) {

            if(c[i]== 'U')
                countUp++; 
            else if (c[i] == 'D') 
                countDown++; 
            else if (c[i] == 'L') 
                countLeft++; 
            else if (c[i] == 'R') 
                countRight++; 
            else 
                count = 0;
        }

        if(countRight >= countLeft){
             x = (countRight - countLeft);
        } else {
             x = (countLeft - countRight);
        }

        if(countUp >= countDown ){
            y = (countUp - countDown);
        } else {
            y = (countDown - countUp);
        } 

        System.out.println("X AXIS IS"+   x   + "  Y AXIS IS  "+ y);
        System.out.println("xaxis "+ xaxis   + "  yaxis  "+ yaxis);
        int finalXaxisPosition = xaxis - x;
        int finalYaxisPosition = yaxis - y;
        System.out.println("Final Position: "+ finalXaxisPosition + "," + finalYaxisPosition);
    }

}
```

Input:

Enter the moving direction:
LRUDL
Enter the X axis co ordinates:
2
Enter the Y axis co ordinates:
2
Enter the initial direction of the robot:
N

Output:
Final Position: 1,2
I have to  get the final direction of the robo after the movement of (LRUDL) from co ordinates (2,2)

Comment: well... if it's facing the last direction it moved in, this seems pretty simple?

Comment: We have four facing direction in the matrix ( North, Souther , West and East) and the movement of robo is (left , right, up , down) ...I need to get the facing direction as the output after the robo movement.

Comment: Yes... so if the robot moves left, is it not also facing left? are you confused as to what directions north, south, east, and west correspond to?

Comment: I don't understand why "facing direction" is relevant to your program if you're not counting the act of *turning* as a move, or tracking it at all. Naturally if the last move the robot makes is to go up, it will be facing: up (north)

Comment: @sleepToken indeed, it would be a less trivial thing if “left” and “right” are turning operations, but then, “up” and “down” would make no sense. Unless we’re talking about [Turtle Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) and “up” and “down” refer to the pen. But then, it would imply that the OP got the task entirely wrong…